# Data structure to store data subject to keys

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

Which data structure is better to use in order to store the following data?:

```
"open" => "11:00", "15:00", "19:00" 
"close" => "12:00", "17:00","20:00"
```

I would need to be able to access data in the following way:

```
dataStructure.get("open").get(0) => "11:00"
```

Comment: Why not `dataStructure.getOpen(0)` ? (with a proper bean class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds you need something like this `Map<String, List<String>>`

`map.get("open")` would return `List<String>` then you can use`get(index)` of List's method.

**Example:**

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();(java 7)
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<List<Stirng>>();(pre java 7)
Consider your first input:
map.get("Open").get(0); would yield 11:00
```

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Date>>()

Comment: @KlausosKlausos sorry, din't understand you, can you be more clear please. :)

Comment: I was unable to compile the code new HashMap<>(); Instead I had to define HashMap<String,List<Date>()

Comment: oh, my bad, it only works in java 7. you have to provide the type arguments in the constructor call in pre java 7

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use a    Map with parameters String and list  to store the above .. Here list would store the number of sub values ......

```
Map map = new HashMap<String,list>

List list = map.get("key")
list.get(0) // will give the 0th value
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use from existing data structure you can have a map something like this ..

```
  Map<String,List<String>> myMap=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();              

  List<String> openList=new ArrayList<String>();       
  openList.add("11:00");       
  openList.add("15:00");                        
  openList.add("19:00");                 

  List<String> closeList=new ArrayList<String>();                     
  closeList.add("12:00");                     
  closeList.add("17:00");            
  closeList.add("20:00");                       

  myMap.put("open",openList);                       
  myMap.put("close",closeList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an array of strings and use open[0], open[1] etc? The same for an array of close strings.